# AngularJS 2.0 - Controller in $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular

Right now my `app.config(...)` looks like this

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/', {
  templateUrl: 'example-list.html',
  controller: 'ExampleListCtrl',
  controllerAs: 'ELCtrl'
}).
when('/:exampleNumber', {
  templateUrl: 'example-detail.html',
  controller: 'ExampleDetailCtrl',
  controllerAs: 'EDCtrl'
}).
otherwise({
  redirectTo: '/'
});
```

But in AngularJS there is going to be no `.controller()`
Is there going to be some change in routing in AngularJS 2.0 or what is the solution for the problem with controller property ?

Comment: I imagine you will be able to do your routing the same only without setting a controller or controllerAs in the route.

Answer (score 0):

The new route configuration will happen in the component level. So I have to guess you set the component instead. But then the component will also do some route configuration when created.